# Can I make a bootstrap collapsible panel only collapse after a password?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <div class="panel-group">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
       <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsiblepanel</a>
       </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Say I had something like this, is there anyway that I can make it so it only collapses after the user enters a correct password from a user prompt using Javascript? Or maybe hide the panel until the user enters a password?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `show.bs.collapse` and `hide.bs.collapse` events and use `preventDefault` to stop the collapsable content from being shown or hidden. Here's an example with a simple confirmation box.

```
$('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    if(!confirm("Allow opening?")){
        return e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You can use the same principle to ask for and check a password. But of course, to make that secure, the password check will need to do a server call, e.g. using $.ajax.